# MySQL connector fails during DbProviderFactories.GetFactory

Tags: mysql, ado.net

I am using MySQL .Net Connector version 6.3.6 in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 in a VB.NET class library using dotnet framework 4. MySql.Data is installed using NuGet. This line of code fails:

```
Dim qdb = Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySqlClient1")
```

With error message "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider."

If I call it with "MySql.Data.MySqlClient":

```
Dim qdb = Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient")
```

The error becomes "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

In *app.config* I put:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="MySqlClient1" />
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySqlClient1" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

How can I get the MySql factory?

Comment: See my answer here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680548/mysql-connector-with-ef-6/21930709#21930709

Answer (score 0):

To use the DbProviderFactory for MySql client, add below config

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories >
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Code usage

```
using (var conn = MySqlDBConnection.CreateConnection(connString))
{
    // TODO
}



public static DbConnection CreateConnection(string connString)
{
     DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");
     var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
     conn.ConnectionString = connString;
     return conn;
}
```